# How to split duplicated separator in Python

Tags: python, split, strsplit

I have a string with the format
`exp = '(( 200 + (4 * 3.14)) / ( 2 ** 3 ))'`

I would like to separate the string into tokens by using `re.split()` and include the separators as well. However, I am not able to split `**` together and eventually being split by `*` instead.

This is my code: `tokens = re.split(r'([+|-|**?|/|(|)])',exp)`

My Output (wrong):

`['(', '(', '200', '+', '(', '4', '*', '3.14', ')', ')', '/', '(', '2', '*', '*', '3', ')', ')']`

I would like to ask is there a way for me to split the separators between `*` and `**`? Thank you so much!

Desired Output:

`['(', '(', '200', '+', '(', '4', '*', '3.14', ')', ')', '/', '(', '2', '**', '3', ')', ')']`

Comment: Ugly but simple: First replace ‚**‘ with any single char that can not appear like underscore. Then split and later replace it back

Comment: @PabloHenkowski oh yah i never though of that! thank you so much!

Comment: Try this regexp: `r'(\*\*|\*|\+|-|/|\(|\))'` (see the `ast` module for a better alternative) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049489/evaluating-mathematical-expressions-in-python

Comment: @VPfB yup this works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [...] notation only allows you to specify individual characters.  To get variable sized alternate patterns you need to use the | operator outside of these brackets.  This also means that you need to escape the regular expression operators and that you need to place the longer patterns before the shorter ones (i.e. ** before *)

```
tokens  = re.split(r'(\*\*|\*|\+|\-|/|\(|\))',exp)
```

or even shorter:

```
tokens = re.split(r'(\*\*|[*+-/()])',exp)
```

Comment: Alright! This pattern really prioritize ** before * ! Thank you so much !