# Breaking an equation step by step based on the arithmetic dependencies in Python

Tags: python, sympy, equation-solving

I am trying to break an equation step by step by checking the arithmetic dependencies. I have tried using the sympy.simplify() and sympy.expand(), but I am not getting the desired output.

Input:

```
m = 10*((9*(x**3) + 2*(y**4))**3) + 3*(y**3 + z)
```

Expected Output:
An array containing all the possibilities as mentioned below

```
output_list = ['10*((9*(x**3) + 2*(y**4))**3)',
               '(9*(x**3) + 2*(y**4))**3',
               '9*(x**3) + 2*(y**4)',
               '9*(x**3)',
               'x**3',
               'x',
               '2*(y**4)',
               'y**4',
               'y',
               '3*(y**3 + z)',
               'y**3 + z',
               'y**3',
               'y',
               'z']
```

I split the equation every time by observing the main dependency to get the next possible dependent equation and finally to the dependent variables.

In the above equation, 10(9(x^3) + 2(y^4))^3, 10 is multiplied after substituting the values of x and y. So, I first removed 10.
Then, I have removed the cube, followed by the addition symbol, and etc. to get the output_list.

How can I get the output_list using Python?

Comment: Not sure I understand your description: when you say "dependency" do you mean arithmetic operator? Because if so, `ast` is built in, and you probably want to have a look at it. (see, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049489/evaluating-mathematical-expressions-in-python)

Comment: Yes, dependency here is the arithmetic operator.
In this equation, 10(9(x^3) + 2(y^4))^3, after substituting the x and y values, the whole answer is getting multiplied by 10. So, I have eliminated 10 first from the considered equation.

Answer (score 0):

This pretty closely gives your expected output by printing the `args` of the expression recursively:

```py
def go(eq):
    if eq.is_Number:return
    if not eq.args:
        print(eq)
    else:
        print(eq)
        for a in eq.args:
            go(a)


>>> go(m)
10*(9*x**3 + 2*y**4)**3 + 3*(y**3 + z)
10*(9*x**3 + 2*y**4)**3
(9*x**3 + 2*y**4)**3
9*x**3 + 2*y**4
9*x**3
x**3
x
2*y**4
y**4
y
3*(y**3 + z)
y**3 + z
y**3
y
z
```

You might also take a look at `preorder_traversal` and `postorder_traversal` which are both in `sympy.core.traversal`.

Comment: It is returning some other below-mentioned values which are not expected.  
`'3*Y**3 + 3*Z + 10*(9*X**3 + 2*Y**4)**3','3*Z','Z','3*Y**3','Y**3','Y'`

Comment: Use `m=S('10*((9*(x**3) + 2*(y**4))**3) + 3*(y**3 + z)',evaluate=False)` or else the 10 will automatically be distributed.